# How to make a variable equal to a list with items removed, without changing original list?

Tags: python, list

I have tried to remove remove items from a list and then make it equal to another variable while still keeping the original list.

Code:

```
print (len(desc1))
desc2 = []
for tuple in desc1:
    for line in tuple:
        if line.endswith(':'):
            desc2 = desc1.remove(tuple)
print (len(desc1))
print (desc2)
```

Output:

```
550 
200
None
```

What I would like the output to be:

```
550
550
200
```

What do I have to use to achieve this?

Comment: `desc2 = [tuple for tuple in desc1 if not any(line.endswith(":") for line in tuple)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy the list first.

```
desc2 = desc1[:]  # shallow copy
for tuple in desc2:
    for line in tuple:
        if line.endswith(":"):
            desc2.remove(tuple)  # don't assign here
```

Note that this is kind of a bad idea anyhow, since you're mutating the list (removing members) as you're iterating over it. In addition, you're using `list.remove` hundreds of times, and it's not exactly quick. Instead consider using a list comprehension.

```
desc2 = [tup for tup in desc1 if not any(line.endswith(":") for line in tup)]
# or
desc2 = filter(lambda t: not any(line.endswith(":") for line in t), desc1)
```

Comment: Changing `for tuple in desc2` to `for tuple in desc1` would remove the ill effects of mutating the list you're iterating (though of course it's still inefficient.)